# Why wouldn't the following query produce the ids and addresses of the most popular apartments?

Tags: sqlite, max, aggregate-functions, having

I have a simple database that contains apartments in one table and the ids of the people interested in those apartments (or their ids) in another. I'm attempting to fetch the apartments with the most people interested in them using a nested query

```
select toh.t, toh.o, toh.h
from (
  select ok.houseid as t, va.houseaddress as o, count ( ok.customerid ) as h
  from house va
    inner join is_interested ok
      on va.houseid = ok.houseid
  group by t
) toh
group by toh.t
  having toh.h = max( toh.h )
;
```

which doesn't do what I want it to do. The inner `select` is supposed to fetch me a table with the IDs, addresses and finally the counts of the IDs of the people interested in them, grouped by apartment ID, which id does admirably.

Therefore the  problem most likely lies with the last two lines:

```
group by toh.t
  having toh.h = max( toh.h )
```

as it returns all of the apartments available, regardless of how many people are interested in them. Changing this to

```
group by toh.t
  having toh.h > 1
```

selects the correct apartments for me (there are at most 2 people interested in said apartments at the moment). It looks like I don't fully understand how the function `max` is supposed to work. Shouldn't `count` return an integer, or is this related to type mismatches at all in the first place? Because it sure looks like it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return the maximum that you want like that.
Use a [`CTE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) to get all the counts from `is_interested` and then join to `house`:

```
with 
  cte as (
    select houseid, count(customerid) counter
    from is_interested
    group by houseid
  )
select h.houseid, h.houseaddress, c.counter
from house h inner join (
  select * from cte
  where counter = (select max(counter) from cte)
) c on c.houseid = h.houseid
```

Comment: This raises the error `Error: near line 1: near "select": syntax error`. The query defined as `cte` seems to be entirely valid to me, so I'm not sure why this happens.

Comment: I removed the `,` before select. Try it now.

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks like the 2 lines pointed out by you:

```
group by toh.t
having toh.h = max( toh.h )
```

have the following meaning:

1. Fetch me groups by `toh.t` key
2. Among those groups display only these that have the value of `toh.h` equal maximum of the values of this field **in the group**. If I am reading correctly this is always the case as there is only one value in `toh.t` in the group.

I believe what you wanted is to take the global maximum across all of the `toh.h` **before grouping**, right?

Comment: Pretty much. But I do not wish to display said maximum itself, only to display the other information based on whether `toh.h` is equal to the maximum.